# Locate and rename duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

There is an existing `baz` table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | label |
+----+-------+
|  1 | foo   |
+----+-------+
|  2 | foo   |
+----+-------+
|  3 | bar   |
+----+-------+
```

The goals are:

- Alter the table by adding a `UNIQUE` index to the `label` column;
- Locate and rename duplicate `label` fields;

**NOTE:** I'd like to avoid copying the table, because it may have thousands of unique fields, while just 2-3 duplicates.

**NOTE2:** I'd like to use `id` as suffix for renamed label, e.g 2nd `foo` becomes `foo_2`.

---

Adding an index:

```
ALTER TABLE baz ADD UNIQUE (label);
```

Now what is the best way to locate and rename the duplicates?

---

**EDIT:** I'd like to:

```
UPDATE (SELECT label, COUNT(*) c FROM baz GROUP BY label HAVING c > 1) t 
SET t.label = (t.label + t.id);
```

or

```
UPDATE baz t1 INNER JOIN baz t2
SET t2.label = t2.label + t2.id 
WHERE t1.label = t2.label;
```

Basically it would:

1. Use `SELECT` query to get duplicates;
2. Process the query and set the value of a `label` like *label + id*;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can add the suffix using variables:

```
set @l = '';
set @rn = 0;

update baz
    set label = concat_ws('_', label,
                          if(@l = label, @rn := @rn + 1,
                             nullif(if(@l := label, @rn := 0, @rn := 0), 0)
                            )
                         )
    order by label, id;
```

Comment: Have tried it and it resolves the task. I thought there is some less complicated (1-2 lines) solution, but I trust blindly your reputation on this matter, @Gordon Linoff.

Comment: Just a question, is it possible to have smth like: `UPDATE (SELECT label, COUNT(*) c FROM baz GROUP BY label HAVING c > 1) t SET t.label = t.id;`?

Comment: @Oleg no,The target table t of the UPDATE is not updatable

Comment: Nevermind, I have updated solution to just use the `id`.